# cron not running in alpine docker

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I have created and added below entry in my `entry-point.sh` for docker file.

```
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond  &

exec "${DIST}/bin/ss" "$@"
```

my crontab.txt looks like below:

```
bash-4.4$ crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /cleanDisk.sh >> /apps/log/cleanDisk.log
```

So when I run the docker container, i don't see any file created called as cleanDisk.log.

I have setup all permissions and crond is running as a process in my container see below.

```
bash-4.4$ ps -ef | grep cron
   12 sdc       0:00 /usr/sbin/crond
  208 sdc       0:00 grep cron
```

SO, can anyone, guide me why the log file is not getting  created?

my cleanDisk.sh looks like below. Since it runs for very first time,and it doesn't match all the criteria, so I would expect at least to print `"No Error file found on Host $(hostname)"` in `cleanDisk.log`.

```
#!/bin/bash

THRESHOLD_LIMIT=20
RETENTION_DAY=3

df -Ph /apps/ | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5,$1 }' | while read output
do
        #echo $output
        used=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | sed s/%//g)
        partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
        if [ $used -ge ${THRESHOLD_LIMIT} ]; then
                echo "The partition \"$partition\" on $(hostname) has used $used% at $(date)"
                FILE_COUNT=$(find ${SDC_LOG} -maxdepth 1 -mtime +${RETENTION_DAY} -type f -name "sdc-*.sdc" -print | wc -l)
                if [ ${FILE_COUNT} -gt 0 ]; then
                        echo "There are ${FILE_COUNT} files older than ${RETENTION_DAY} days on Host $(hostname)."
                        for FILENAME in $(find ${SDC_LOG} -maxdepth 1 -mtime +${RETENTION_DAY} -type f -name "sdc-*.sdc" -print);
                        do
                                ERROR_FILE_SIZE=$(stat -c%s ${FILENAME} | awk '{ split( "B KB MB GB TB PB" , v ); s=1; while( $1>1024 ){ $1/=1024; s++ } printf "%.2f %s\n", $1, v[s] }')
                                echo "Before Deleting Error file ${FILENAME}, the size was ${ERROR_FILE_SIZE}."
                                rm -rf ${FILENAME}
                                rc=$?
                                if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]];
                                then
                                        echo "Error log file ${FILENAME} with size ${ERROR_FILE_SIZE} is deleted on Host $(hostname)."
                                fi
                        done
                fi
                if [ ${FILE_COUNT} -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "No Error file found on Host $(hostname)."
                fi
        fi

done
```

***edit***

my docker file looks like this

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u192-b12-alpine

ARG SDC_UID=20159
ARG SDC_GID=20159
ARG SDC_USER=sdc

RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash \
    busybox-suid \
    sudo && \
    echo 'hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4' >> /etc/nsswitch.conf

RUN addgroup --system ${SDC_USER} && \
    adduser --system --disabled-password -u ${SDC_UID} -G ${SDC_USER} ${SDC_USER}

ADD --chown=sdc:sdc crontab.txt /etc/crontabs/sdc/

RUN chgrp sdc /etc/cron.d /etc/crontabs /usr/bin/crontab 

# Also tried to run like this but not working
# RUN /usr/bin/crontab  -u sdc /etc/crontabs/sdc/crontab.txt

USER ${SDC_USER}
EXPOSE 18631

RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/crontabs/sdc/crontab.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["dc", "-exec"]
```

Comment: You're recording `stdout` from your script to `/apps/log/cleanDisk.log`, but what about `stderr`? There might be something useful there.  Add `2>&1` to your crontab invocation, then see if anything shows up in the log.

Comment: I ran it manually, it just doing fine. But it's good idea, I will add it.

Comment: I see I'm using non root user to run the cron, hence it's throwing all kind of erros or permission denied. So anyone have any idea how to run busybox one crond for alpine to run as non root user?

Comment: this is what I did right now in my docker file `ADD --chown=appuser:appgroup crontab.txt  /etc/crontabs/appuser` . and it's still not running and my crontab.txt `*/5 * * * * /cleanDisk.sh >> /apps/log/cleanDisk.log 2>&1` and don't see any error as well. So is there any other way to run the crond using non root user?

Comment: @larsks any thought? I tried a lot but seems not able to work? may be any alternative?

Comment: Can you update your question so that it includes a Dockerfile and anything else necessary to reproduce the problem? That would make it easier to figure out what's going on. Right now we don't even know what base image you're using.

Comment: @larsks edited original question.

Comment: You don't appear to ever be `ADD`ing or `COPY`ing your `docker-entrypoint.sh` script into your image. And there's no `/etc/cron.d`, so the build fails on that `RUN chgrp...` statement.

Comment: And even if you fix the `chgrp`, running `crontab` fails because it's no longer `suid`.  You can't possibly be seeing the behavior you're describing because your Dockerfile doesn't build for multiple reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206805/discussion-between-change198-and-larsks).